# Edit summary isn't saved when editing an edit

Tags: bug, edits, editing-help

When editing an edit, I have the possiblity to update the "Edit summary" field, but after clicking on "Save edits", my changes to the "Edit summary" field are not reflected. Why is that?

Comment: On main or meta? By editing an edit do you mean "Improve edit"? Can you show an example, maybe in the form of images or a gif?

Comment: @Tomerikoo I think OP means they are editing again during the 5 minutes grace period.

Comment: On main Stack overflow. To reproduce : edit a question, add an "Edit summary" (or not), then edit the edit. At this point, change the "Edit summary" and save. I don't see my changes.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I most probably did that within 5 minutes, yes, not sure what the "grace period" is about though.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat well, the question seems identical, yes, but no real answer was provided, or did I miss anything? One thing is for sure, when I fill in a form field and hit save and see no message and my changes aren't saved, I'd say it is a very bad UX.

Comment: @MrUpsidown unfortunately there isn't any response or indication that the feature request is accepted / rejected / in-review. But it is the same question yes.

Comment: This is a FAQ (because the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) is violated). Samples: *[Let me add or change edit summary during edit window (grace period)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79180/)*, *[Please save my edit summary when edited within grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250729)*, *[Editing edit summaries](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96918)*, and *[Changes to edit summaries are turfed with no notice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189031)*. There must also be several duplicates on this meta site.

Comment: My macro keyboard (or rather particular macro key sequences) adds two extra empty lines at the end of the body to prevent this problem (to be on the safe side).